# Switching between lmerTest and lme4

Tags: r, lme4

Is it possible to down-cast `merModLmerTest` objects from `lmerTest` into `merMod` objects in `lme4`? I have a number of use cases where I need to toggle between formats.

According to the lmerTest docs:

> The merModLmerTest contains merMod class of lme4 package and overloads anova and summary functions.

However, I can't figure out how the inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

`lmerModLmerTest` objects are almost identical to `merMod` objects, but have a few extra slots.  There may be an elegant way to reduce them, but I did it by brute force (it was a little trickier than I thought because of some of the evaluation that the `new()` function does.)

Example:

```
library(lme4)
fm0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
library(lmerTest)
fm1 <- as(fm0,"lmerModLmerTest")
```

This is probably the wrong way to set things up (should use `setAs()` etc.) but ...

```
as.merMod.lmerModLmerTest <- function(x) {
  r <- list(Class="lmerMod")
  for (s in names(getSlots("merMod"))) {
     r[[s]] <- slot(x,s)
  }
  r$resp <- quote(x@resp)
  r$call <- quote(x@call) ## protect from evaluation
  do.call(new,r)
}
```

Try it:

```
fm2 <- as.merMod.lmerModLmerTest(fm1)
all.equal(fm0,fm2) ## TRUE
```